# Plotting bar and reverse bar into the Y axis

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to plot two sequences of bars, using the same y-axis. One of the sequences goes on the bottom, the other goes on top (from top to bottom), and the y axis is split into two (half for the bottom bars and half for the top bars). The bottom bars use one color, like green, and the top bars use another color, red, and the y axis uses the respective colors on each half on the axis.

Example:
[image]

**Question:** How can I split the y-axis in the way represented in the figure above?

Thanks for helping! =D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create this effect by layering three axes and adjusting [their properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) accordingly. For example:

```
% The larger left axes:
hLeft = axes('Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8], ...  % Normalized position
             'XLim', [0 11], 'YLim', [0 3], ...  % Set desired limits
             'Box', 'off');                      % Turn off outline
hLeft.XLabel.String = 'Time';         % Add an x label
hLeft.YLabel.String = 'Line';         % Add a y label
hLeft.Title.String = 'Bar-bar-plot';  % Add a title
hLine = line(hLeft, 1:10, rand(1,10)+1, 'Color', 'k');  % Plot a sample line

% The lower right axes:
hLower = axes('Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.4], ...         % Position over bottom half
              'XLim', [0 11], 'YLim', [0 1.5], ...       % Set desired limits
              'YColor', [0 0.5 0], 'Color', 'none', ...  % Change colors
              'YAxisLocation', 'right');                 % Position y axis
hLower.XAxis.Visible = 'off';    % Turn of x axis
hLower.YLabel.String = 'Bar 1';  % Add a y label
hold on;
hBarLower = bar(hLower, 1:10, rand(1,10), ...  % A sample bar plot
                'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [0 0.5 0]);

% The upper right axes:
hUpper = axes('Position', [0.1 0.5 0.8 0.4], ...       % Position over top half
              'XLim', [0 11], 'YLim', [0 1.5], ...     % Set desired limits
              'YColor', [1 0 0], 'Color', 'none', ...  % Change colors
              'YAxisLocation', 'right', ...            % Position y axis
              'YDir', 'reverse');                      % Reverse y axis
hUpper.XAxis.Visible = 'off';    % Turn off x axis
hUpper.YLabel.String = 'Bar 2';  % Add a y label
hold on;
hBarUpper = bar(hUpper, 1:10, rand(1,10), ...  % A sample bar plot
                'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', [1 0 0]);

% Add a legend:
hLegend = legend(hUpper, [hLine hBarLower hBarUpper], ...
                 {'line', 'bar 1', 'bar 2'}, 'Color', 'w');
```

And here's the plot:

[image]

You can reposition the legend as needed by left clicking on it and dragging it to the best spot.

Comment: WOW! That's a very elegant and incredibly well explained solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: For those working with serial dates, you must add the `datetick` command after each plot on a different axis. For example, imagine you first plot on the left axis, then call `datetick`, and then you move on to plotting on the bottom right axis, then you call `datetick` again, and then you move on to the top right axis, and you should call `datetick` again. This makes sure that your x-axis are properly aligned.

Comment: Adding a title seems to break the figure, the graph is pushed down and the other hidden graph appears.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: Which axes are you adding the title to? It works fine when I add one to the left axis: `hLeft.Title.String='hello';`

Comment: It works fine with labels on both sides on both axis. The problem occurs when I add a "main" title to the graph on the top, using `title("some title")`. I am also trying to find a way to put the legends together, as of now I have a legend for the line, which is separate from the legend for the bar graph on the bottom, which is separate from the legend for the bar graph on the top.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: I can't reproduce the issue you are having with the title, but I have a solution for the legend. I'll edit it in.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code, it really helped!!! The legends worked perfectly, all I had to do was give a name for each of my plots, like `hPlot1`. I don't know why but if I call the `hLeft.Title.String` before actually plotting anything, the title disappears as soon as the first plot on the left axes appears. I fixed this by first plotting everything I needed on the left axes, and then giving the figure a title, no problems happened when I plotted on the other axes.